# where to add logic that would apply to the global type dropdown in storybook 8?

Tags: storybook

I posted the question in detail here:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/discussions/26687

But posting it here as well to get more eyes on it.

The TL:DR; of it is that I made a new global type and I added and it looks great, I just don't know how to wire up functionality to it.

The example is below and if you go to the ledger icon at the top you will see I can have versions there, and the values are the URL, I just don't know if there is a special way to wire up the logic.

https://llqiygklqgithub-g1f4--6006--7dbe22a9.local-credentialless.webcontainer.io/